# How to keep a nice table, it won't line up properly

Tags: tables

Basically i'm trying to make a 2x8 table with a variable in the first column with horizontal lines but it won't line up and keeps adding the word "height" into the table when viewed as a pdf. I can't find any similar problems on here.
Thanks in advance

Here's an example of my problem

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| }
\hline
$x$ & 2.9 & 2.99 & 2.999 & 3 & 3.001 & 3.01 &3.1
\hline
y & 1.9 & 1.99 & 1.999 & \textbf{DNE} & 2.001 & 2.01 & 2.1
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

1. You need a `\\` at the end of each line and then `\hline`.
2. Use `newcolumntype` to define a new column C with equal width.
3. Increase `arraystretch` to have a nice vertical padding.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ *{8}{|C}| }
\hline
$x$ & 2.9 & 2.99 & 2.999 & 3 & 3.001 & 3.01 &3.1\\
\hline
y & 1.9 & 1.99 & 1.999 & \textbf{DNE} & 2.001 & 2.01 & 2.1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, user59696.

Comment: @user59696 Could you mark this as solved then?